# How can I get results back from calls to Cache facade?

Tags: php, caching, laravel, memcached, laravel-4

I am using memcached as the driver for my cache in a Laravel 4 application. The Laravel implementation of the driver does not have a return value for any of the methods, and I was hoping someone could help me figure out how to get what I need, whether it's available in Laravel or helping me extend the driver.

Specifically what I need is the status of calls to `add`...so, if `add` is successful, I get true or false if it fails. Today, I get `null` for every call, and this isn't incredibly useful when trying to use memcached for a simple locking system.

Can anyone provide a solution?

EDIT: I was looking at the `MemcachedStore` class, and there isn't even an `add` function. So,I figured I'd just extend that class, but will `Cache::add()` call that function even though `StoreInterface` (the interface that `MemcachedStore` implements) doesn't have an `add` function? I guess I'm asking, how would `Cache::add()` map to my implementation of `add()`?

Answer (score 0):

An Interface doesn't need to have all methods we have on implementations of that Interface, but a class that extends an Interface must implement all Interface methods.

Implementations will have different methods, because different implementations will do things differently.

What you're looking for is the Cache Repository:

```
vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Cache\Repository.php
```

There you'll find the `add()` method, but you're sure is this one you're looking for?

Laravel uses `put()` and `get()` to save information on cache, as you can see in the docs: http://laravel.com/docs/cache.

Besides that, I think that we will need more information.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure I need `add` because I need to know if the key already exists in the cache...`put` will replace the value if the key already exists. What I ended up doing was just calling `Cache::getMemcached()` to get the Memcached instance, and I just called the functions from that object instead. Not very elegant I suppose, but it gets the job done. I'll worry about elegance after the deadline.

Comment: Haha, yeah, sometimes we just need to get the thing done. Good luck!